# Apps zoomed / excessively scaled in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, display

A lot of my apps on ubuntu is super zoomed weirdly. I don't know why am I facing such issues. I have gone through a lot of settings and nothing has been changed in particular. Let me show some examples.

[Spyder loading screen is zoomed during loading.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAx9C.png)

[Zoom is zoomed when it is open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWCUE.png)

[Spyder has this wierd scaled up IDE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXfcA.png)

[My notes app is also scaled up insanely.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xBBF.png)

I wasn't facing this issue before, but suddenly now I am facing this (maybe after my update to 20.04). I havent changed any display settings.

Comment: I checked it all. There is nothing atm.

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've done so far to prevent suggestions that have already failed.